# Embed pdf to have width dynamically fill col-sm-6

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, embed

I know there are a LOT of questions about embedding pdfs, and this one is different as I am focusing specifically on getting the width of my pdf to dynamically scale to the width of the bootstrap "col-sm-6" that I want the pdf inside.

I have played with embed, pdf.js, readstep2.html, and google pdf viewer.
But, all of them seem to require some sort of "width and height" setting.

In a perfect world, I'd like to have a single pdf window with some page left/right buttons at the bottom that shows the full pdf height, and dynamically grows and shrinks so that the width always fills the "col-sm-6" element it's inside of. Here's my current code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <p>Filler text here</p>
                    <br>
                    <audio controls>
            <source src="media/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
                    <br><br>
                    <embed src="media/song.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">


                    </div>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Have you tried just tossing it into an iFrame?